# Connect to site through https

Tags: java, https

I have some application that should connect to https Site, and receive some.
With connection all is ok, but when i what getInputStream() comes Exception:

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:

Here is the part of code:

```
    String query = siteURL.toExternalForm();

    URL queryURL = new URL(query);

    String data = "username="+login+"&password="+password;

    URLConnection connection = queryURL.openConnection();

    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection
            .getOutputStream());
    writer.write(data);
    writer.flush();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Are you sure that username and password are as parameters? Usually (especially on secure) there are in request headers.

Comment: But when I try to connect to this resource via browser all is ok. For example:
if query = https://url/WebHome
   data = username=Test&password=test

https://url/WebHome?username=Test&password=test

Comment: I have tried so, 

connection.addRequestProperty("username", login);
connection.addRequestProperty("password", password);

but the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not allowed to do what you're trying to do, you're getting an [HTTP 403: Forbidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).

Can you open the same URL in your browser?

Comment: Funny thing, that i can open it in the browser
And i have found that, actually if I try to connection.connect();
then variable connected is false...

Answer (score 1):

I think the site have a custom authentication mechanism, in wich you have to supply our username and password as GET parameters. So your url should look like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://somesite.org/page?username=<username>&password=password");
... = url.openConnection();
...
```

If you use url.openConnection, a HTTP GET request is done. If you want to send data with a request, you must use a HTTP POST request. In this case, you can use a third party library, like Apache Commons HttpClient.

BTW: why are u creating a new URL object, if you already have one?

Comment: It doesn't works((


BTW: why are u creating a new URL object, if you already have one?
>> I have only one URL object -> queryURL

Comment: Salandur is however probably right. You are making a GET request to the server, but try to write the request parameters in the request body, which is usually only supported with a POST request.

Comment: @Le_Coeur: you must have an other one, since you are calling String query = siteURL.toExternalForm();

Comment: I have erased some code from the beginnig, it was
 String query = siteURL.toExternalForm()+"/var/start";